# Solve a diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

The questions is: Solve in the positive integers $$3^n=m^4+m+1.$$
I can prove that $n$ is odd, and $m\equiv 4(\text{mod }9)$, but i dont know why $n$ and $m$ are $1$.

Comment: for $n\ge2$, $3^n\equiv0\pmod9$

Comment: But $m=1$ is a solution, contrary to your proof that $m\equiv 4 \bmod 9$.

Comment: Perhaps OP means $m\equiv4\pmod9$ if $n\ge2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner We know this, yes. I was curious what the OP actually has proved himself. He doesn't show what he has done.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, if $n=1$ then $m=1$, if $n=2$ there is not solutions, if $n\geq 3$ then $m\equiv 22(\text{mod }27)$, and if n is even, then $(3^k-n^2)(3^k+n^2)=n+1$, but $n^2+3^k>n+1$

Comment: How do you prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not of much use but some elementary observations about the numbers $m^4+m+1$ are as follows.

There is precisely one solution modulo $3^n$ of the equation 
$$m^4+m+1\equiv 0\pmod {3^n}$$
The solution for $3^{n+1}$ can be obtained from the solution for $3^n$ as follows:-

If $m^4+m+1\equiv 3^nd\pmod {3^{n+1}}$, where $d=1$ or $2$, then 
$$(m+3^nd)^4+(m+3^nd)+1\equiv 0\pmod {3^{n+1}}$$

The first few solutions are then

$m=1:$    $m^4+m+1\equiv 3\pmod {3^2}$

$m=1+3=4:$    $m^4+m+1\equiv 2\times 3^2\pmod {3^3}$

$m=4+2\times 3^2=22:$    $m^4+m+1\equiv  3^3\pmod {3^4}$

$m=22+3^3=49:$    $m^4+m+1\equiv 2\times 3^4\pmod {3^5}$

$m=49+2\times3^4=211:$    $m^4+m+1\equiv 3^7\pmod {3^8}$

$m=211+3^7=2398:$    $m^4+m+1\equiv 2\times 3^8\pmod {3^9}$